# Implementing GraphQL (GraphQL for .Net) in ASP.NET Core, why is my Query:ObjectGraphType class not being registered by dependency injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, graphql

I've setup a basic Web Api demonstrate the use of GraphQL using ASP.Net Core. I've Followed a tutorial, what feels like exactly but am getting an error I don't understand.

I'm using GraphQL for .NET v2.4.0

This is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Land.GraphQL.Queries.LandQuery' has been registered.
  at at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
  at at GraphQL.FuncDependencyResolver.Resolve(Type type)
  at at GraphQL.FuncDependencyResolver.Resolve[T]()
  at Land.GraphQL.LandSchema..ctor(IDependencyResolver resolver) in .../LandSchema.cs:11
```

I'd be grateful for any light shed :)

Here's the code:

I created a LandType:ObjectGraphType to define the Type:

```
    public class LandType : ObjectGraphType<Entities.Land>
    {
        public LandType(ILandDataAccess landDataAccess)
        {
            Name = "Land";

            Field(land => land.Id, type: typeof(IdGraphType)).Description("Land Id in LandApi context");
            Field(land => land.Apn)
                .Description(
                    "Assessor's Parcel Number (APN) is a unique number that is assigned to each tract of land in a county by the Tax Assessor.");
            Field(land => land.Address).Description("");
            Field(land => land.ZipCode).Description("");
            Field(land => land.City).Description("");
            Field(land => land.County).Description("");
            Field(land => land.State).Description("");
            Field(land => land.Country).Description("");
            Field(land => land.GisNumber).Description("");
            Field(land => land.AssessedValue).Description("");
            Field(land => land.LegalDescription).Description("");
            Field(land => land.Acreage, type: typeof(FloatGraphType)).Description("Acreage of Land");

        }
    }
```

I created a LandQuery:ObjectGraphType to define the Query:

```
public class LandQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public LandQuery(ILandDataAccess dataAccess)
        {
            Field<ListGraphType<LandType>>(
                "Land", 
                resolve: context => dataAccess.GetLandsAsync());
        }
    }
```

I created a LandSchema:Schema to define the Schema:

```
public class LandSchema : Schema
    {
        public LandSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver) : base(resolver)
        {
            Query = resolver.Resolve<LandQuery>();
        }
    }
```

I added the service and middleware to the Startup file:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(s => new FuncDependencyResolver(
                s.GetRequiredService));

            services.AddScoped<LandSchema>();

            services.AddGraphQL(o => { o.ExposeExceptions = true; })
                .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
                app.UseGraphQL<LandSchema>();
        }
```

---

Edit:

Thanks to the commenters @NateBarbettini and @TonyNgo inspired me to find the answer. Turns out `.AddGraphTypes` only searches the calling assembly. My GraphTypes are stored in a referenced Assembly. passing the referenced assembly fixed the problem: `.AddGraphTypes(typeof(LandSchema).Assembly, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a great question, kudos.

Comment: Thanks to the commenters @NateBarbettini and @TonyNgo inspired me to find the answer. Turns out `.AddGraphTypes` only searches the calling assembly. My GraphTypes are stored in a referenced Assembly. passing the referenced assembly fixed the problem: `.AddGraphTypes(typeof(LandSchema).Assembly, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing this line of code in your ConfigureServices.

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(s => new FuncDependencyResolver (
        s.GetRequiredService));

    services.AddScoped<LandSchema>();
    services.AddGraphQL(x => {
            x.ExposeExceptions = true; //set true only in development mode. make it switchable.
        })
        .AddGraphTypes (ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
}
```

If that is not the case you can read my blog [here](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/06/02/building-fullstack-web-app-with-net-core-2-2-angular-8-graphql/)

Comment: So I do have that line of code in there, sorry I went ahead and added it.

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL.NET requires you to explicitly register a lot of things. Quick answer: you need to register `LandQuery`.

You have:

```
services.AddScoped<IDependencyResolver>(s => new FuncDependencyResolver(s.GetRequiredService));
```

The `IDependencyResolver` acts as a "glue" between the GraphQL.NET system (which needs to request a lot of service types) and ASP.NET Core's service collection (which contains the service types).

The object graph that you're giving to GraphQL.NET starts with `LandSchema`, which is correctly registered:

```
services.AddScoped<LandSchema>();
```

But look at what `LandSchema` is doing!

```
Query = resolver.Resolve<LandQuery>();
```

This line asks the `IDependencyResolver` for a `LandQuery` service type. Your `FuncDependencyResolver` is pointing at the ASP.NET Core service collection, so this will succeed if `LandQuery` is registered. It isn't, which is why you are getting the error

> No service for type 'Land.GraphQL.Queries.LandQuery' has been registered.

To fix it, add a few new lines to `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<LandQuery>();
services.AddScoped<LandType>();
```

Any type or service (including `ILandDataAccess`) required by one of the GraphQL types will need to be registered in `ConfigureServices`. If you don't want to hand-register every single GraphQL.NET type, use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) to auto-register types that derive from `GraphType`:

```
// Add all classes that represent graph types
services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<LandQuery>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<GraphQL.Types.GraphType>())
        .AsSelf()
        .WithSingletonLifetime());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Registering the services individually does work. I accidentally omitted this line in my original post:

`services.AddGraphQL(o => { o.ExposeExceptions = true; })
                .AddGraphTypes(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);`

I think you're absolutely right that the services can be auto-registered. My understanding is that this^ line does that. However your post inspired me, the GraphTypes are located in a referenced assembly, so my guess is that they are not being scanned. Not sure how to do that with the above code. Maybe I will use Scrutor... :/

Comment: @teaMonkeyFruit Ah, interesting. I hadn't seen the `AddGraphTypes` method. I learned something new too :)

Answer (score -1):

EDITED:

Some months ago I created a .net core graphql project.

In the real-life, you need to tune the original library.

I want to share some tricks and common classes that help you to build a .net core graphql solution.

For example, I've created an automapper that automatically convert your dto model into a ObjectGraphType (output) and InputObjectGraphType (input).

But not only this.

For example you can't use efficiently dbcontext if you register it using AddDbContext (scoped) like a classical .net core web api, because you need to register Graphql middleware as singleton, so AddDbContext is a "fake scoped" because it is used inside a "singleton middleware".

This means that context using AddDbContext is instantiated just once at startup!
So, you will have problem of simultaneous access to the connection.

But I have solution: use factory pattern.

If you want a complete code example, see here:
https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/576#issuecomment-626661695

Comment: @Arion: This may not be a particularly _useful_ answer since it’s not very focused, but it’s certainly _an_ answer, and of at least some relevance to the topic. E.g., it’s not gibberish, asking a new question, saying “thank you”, or “me too!” That said, I’d certainly encourage the author to try to focus in on the OP’s original question. A walkthrough of an existing GraphQL application would be better served by a blog post.

Comment: @Alessandro Lazzara, do you think you could condense this answer? If there's no way to fit everything you want to say into a single answer, you could post a short but complete answer here and link to the full details elsewhere. Using two answers to say one thing isn't really supported.

Comment: I've edited my answer with summary and external link that have complete code